# Addition of a parent item in POM causes JDK version to change

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, version, pom.xml

In one of the classes I have this code:

```
str.isEmpty()
```

which compiles fine until I add this element to the POM:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>teevra.platform.parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.hs.fusion</groupId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

And then immediately the eclipse starts giving an error saying *"The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type String*". I obviously need this parent to access classes/interfaces needed for this child project.

I wonder what is causing the shift from Java Version 1.6 to 1.4 and how can it be prevented? Even more baffling is the fact that from command prompt, the project builds fine but not in Eclipse Juno.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the specific version of java to use. your problem is probably that your eclipse default is different from the maven default, so as soon as you add the dependency, m2e regenerates the project settings using the maven default (1.5)

Just specify the required java version explicitly. Something like this in your *plugins* section

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
       <source>1.6</source>
       <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that no invalid JRE calls leak into your project, you should use http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer/ It seems like your parent lowered the source/target of the [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)